# How to display posts of a specific category without using ul and li tags in WordPress?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to show 10 recent posts from a category using the code below:

```
<div id="slideShow" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <?php
        $my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=10&cat=4');
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) :
            $my_query->the_post();
            $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) : ?>
                        <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'carousel'); ?>
                        <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" class="slideShowImage d-block mx-auto" alt="carouselImage" width="1100" height="500">
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

The problem is that this piece of code does not show the posts until I add ul and li tags to it:

```
<div id="slideShow" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <ul id="carouselPosts">
            <?php
            $my_query = new WP_Query('showposts=10&cat=4');
            while ($my_query->have_posts()) :
                 $my_query->the_post();
                 $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
                 <li class="list-unstyled">
                     <div class="carousel-item active">
                         <?php if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) : ?>
                             <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'carousel'); ?>
                             <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" class="slideShowImage d-block mx-auto" alt="carouselImage" width="1100" height="500">
                         <?php endif; ?>
                         <div class="carousel-caption">
                             <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                             <?php the_content(); ?>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </li>
             <?php endwhile; ?>
         </ul>
     </div>
 </div>
```

**I just want to use the code as it is without adding ul and li tags. Also, I don't want to use any plugins like Bootstrap carousel. Finally, for those who want to suggest keeping ul and li tags, I want to say as in another part of my website I've used Bootstrap card decks, I'm gonna face the same problem in 
that section too. Another point is that I don't want to add extra CSS and JavaScript to my code.**

Comment: So remove the carousel code and use your loop.

Comment: @HowardE It doesn't work without ul and li tags

Comment: @parisa in your first code closing div for class="carousel-inner" is missing have you seen that?

Comment: Your question is unclear. This is why people have probably down voted it. Maybe if you clarify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot, I found this solution and it works very well for me:

```
<div id="slideShow" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'published',
        'cat' => '4',
        'showposts' => '10',
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) :
        $my_query->the_post();
        $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail($post->ID)) : ?>
                <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'carousel'); ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" class="slideShowImage d-block mx-auto" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```